# org.jboss.mq.SpyJMSException: Connection Failed

Tags: java, jboss

In our product we keep on getting this error in logs. Nothing fails due to this. But don't know how to avoid this exception trace and the root cause of this exception. Give me some solution for this...

```
[15:00:10:441]|[01-16-2014]|[SYSOUT]|[INFO]|[78]|: [JBOSS] Connection: Connection failure: org.jboss.mq.SpyJMSException: Connection Failed; - nested throwable: (java.io.IOException: ping timeout.)
    at org.jboss.mq.Connection.asynchFailure(Connection.java:436)
    at org.jboss.mq.Connection$PingTask.run(Connection.java:1385)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.ClockDaemon$RunLoop.run(ClockDaemon.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: ping timeout.
    at org.jboss.mq.Connection$PingTask.run(Connection.java:1377)
    ... 2 more
```